# Inter VPC internet access between lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I am working on a project where my main lambda function is in a VPC in private subnet and some sister lambda functions in a different VPC which are in their own private subnets. How can I go about calling these sister lambdas's from the main lambda across VPC without giving internet access to each of them via a NAT gateway linking to a public subnet which has an internet gateway attached to it.
Other AWS services that my main lambda invokes are:
1. S3
2. Dynamodb
3. Autoscaling
4. ECS
5. RDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but there are some complex steps involved.

First of all, when you use `aws-sdk`, the calls are made through the internet. To avoid this situation and access the services within the AWS network, The AWS has introduced some private VPC endpoints. I have only used S3 and API gateway private endpoints to date. But there is more type of VPC endpoints.

This is how I would do today,

1. setup a private API gateway API to invoke lambda - The private API's are only accessible through a private VPC endpoint for API gateway.
2. create a private VPC endpoint for API gateway.
3. setup VPC peering between the VPCs
4. (from the sister lambda on other VPC) invoke the API through the VPC endpoints public DNS URL

The drawback of adding an API in front of the lambda is, the API has a hard timeout of 29 seconds.

hope this helps.

Comment: I do not want to invoke the main lambda from sister lambda but the other way around where my main lambda already has an API gateway in front of it and the sister lambda's actually have algorithm code which is invoked from this main lambda and response is returned back from the main lambda and served on the Frontend using the API gateway.I dont think I will need an VPC endpoint for API gateway. please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: if the main lambda has outgoing internet access, It can call the sister lambdas through the internet.

Comment: if the main lambda does not have outgoing internet access, it would need to call the sister lambda via a private VPC endpoint for API gateway.  this requires the sister lambdas to be invoked by an API (private) as well.

Comment: so what your are suggesting is that we have an API gateway in front of the sister lambdas and define VPC endpoint for that API gateway in the main lambda. This new API gateway will then invoke the sister lambda and do the necessary stuff.

Comment: Close. Vpc gateway in sister vpc, vpc end point in sister vpc. Main vpc lambdas talk to sister lambda through sister vpc endpoints public dns url.